# Table view images not loading with or without DispatchQueue

Tags: swift, uitableview, asynchronous, grand-central-dispatch

I'm using the SDWebImage library to load images into my table cells as imageView. 
I'm having a similar issue to 
 this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30066625/uiimageview-in-table-view-not-showing-until-clicked-on-or-device-is-roatated); my tableView loads but without the images. When I click on a cell and then go back to the main page, the images have finally loaded. But I want the images to load without having to do that (without any interaction).

However, removing the DispacheQueue.main.async doesn't fix the issue; the images still aren't loaded. I read that cell.setNeedsLayout() and
cell.layoutIfNeeded() were supposed to help fix this, but they didn't.

myURLss is my array of URLs, by the way

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PostCell")

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            cell?.imageView?.sd_setImage(with: self.myURLss[indexPath.row])
            cell?.setNeedsLayout()
        }

    return cell!

}
```

Comment: You are already using SDWebImage that loads images in Async mode then what made you use DispatchQueue here again ? Remove that DispatchQueue and try Please

Comment: @iOSGeek same issue, still doesn't load the images immediately

Comment: Then please check do url you providing really contains a Image ?

Comment: @iOSGeek yes, it loads after I click on a cell and then go back to the original screen

Comment: Can you share Project if possible ?

Comment: Did you tried adding a placeholder image till image Is not loaded from SDWebImage ? I too had faced same issue I fixed it using a placeholder image

Comment: Can you compress the Project folder and update its zipped file ?

Comment: I was not able to run your project but I tried creating a sample using your defined arrays It worked for me Should I share that sample project created ?

Comment: @iOSGeek That would be great, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried using SDWebImage Check Project at Link -

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1BQ_3fFvD04BnGa5uRqbAtU4DWGn_Pzpq

I created My custom cell class in which imageView is Connected and updating it in cellFOrRowAt of TableView

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {

    //My ImageView
    @IBOutlet weak var myImageView: UIImageView!

    override func awakeFromNib()
    {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

My TableView CellForRowAt

```
 //Setting cells data
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {

        let cell = self.myTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier) as! CustomCell

        DispatchQueue.main.async
            {
            cell.myImageView.sd_setImage(with: self.myURLss[indexPath.row], completed: nil)
        }

        return cell
    }
```

Also as you are using SDWebImage Library they provide set of options To us

if still image in your code does not show try using below line

```
cell.myImageView.sd_setImage(with: self.myURLss[indexPath.row], placeholderImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "malee"), options: .continueInBackground, completed: nil)
```

Hope It helps

Comment: Happy to help , as I said same I faced earlier it helped me setting a placeholder Image

Answer (score 0):

you can reload row after loaded image.

```
    cell?.imageView?.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: your.url), completed: {_,_,_,_ in 
        self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
    })
```